# Django admin: use checkboxes in list view in list_filter()

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model `Transaction` with a ForeignKey to another model (`TransactionState`) on `state` field. So in `admin.py` I have:

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_filter = ('state', )
    ...
```

In `TransactionState` I have records like "paid", "unpaid", "delivered", "canceled", Etc. and it works fine but I want to be able to filter using checkboxes to allow multiple selection like "paid" OR "delivered". It's possible?

Comment: in the admin panel? No... not without overriding the Form and the list html template

Comment: @warath-coder yes, on the right side of the list view of the model. I'll wait to new versions, maybe will be easier in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For all models

You can easily [override the django admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) to customize the admin UI.

To edit the sidebar filter, just add a `templates/admin/filter.html` file, and write your custom HTML with radio buttons.

Note that this will change the sidebar filter for all models.

### For a single model

If you want to change the filter for a single model, you can specify a template for a `ListFilter`:

```
class FilterWithCustomTemplate(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    template = "custom_template.html"
```

### Example

As a reference example, check is the [default template for filter.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/filter.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. Radio buttons cannot have multiple selection, you would need to make them check boxes.
2. What you are looking for is making custom filters. I would suggest instead of overwriting the Filter List to contain a check form with check boxes, add a custom filter with each option as a filter. Use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) link and scroll down to the SimpleListFilter and you will be able to code it with 5-10 LOC.